# Nested pagination graphql query

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, nestjs

i'm somewhat new to graphql, i want to know if it possible to implement either offset or cursor pagination for nested graphql object,

let take an example :

```
query Query($poolId: Int!) {
  pool(id: $poolId) {
    id
    title
    questions {
      id
      description
      choices {
        description
        id
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

what is the best way to paginate pool questions and choices?

Thanks